# In Haskell, what is the most common way to apply a function to every Nth element of a list?

Tags: list, haskell, repeat, sieve-of-eratosthenes, circular-list

Its very common where I come across some list of elements `xs` and want to do something to do something with every Nth element. The simplest example would be the Sieve or Erastothenes, where you want to "knock out" every multiple of a given prime. The two ways I could do this would be explicit recursion passing along a counter variable; or `zipWith ($) (cycle (replicate (n-1) id ++ f))`. So which way is better/more elegant/more commonly used, or is there some library function like `mapEveryN :: (a -> a) -> Int -> [a] -> [a]` that I haven't found?

Comment: Well, you could do `zipWith ($) (drop 1 $ cycle $ f : replicate (n - 1) id)`, which seems to be pretty elegant to me.  There's no explicit recursion, you avoid concatenation and instead use `:`, and it's a 1-liner.

Comment: You can also obtain an intermediate list with `piecesOf n = unfoldr (Just . splitAt n)` then `concatMap` through it with whatever. Probably not as short and efficient as other methods but can be convenient sometimes.

Comment: @n.m. `piecesOf` creates groups of `n`, followed by a group that may be less than `n`, followed by an infinite number of empty groups.

Comment: @pat yeah, it's for infinite lists... why would anyone settle for less? :)

Comment: this is probably not the best way to implement the sieve of eratosphenes, but what you've got is pretty good as a "apply to every n-th" solution, although I'd do it @bheklilr style

Comment: I would say that recursion is the best way to do it.

Comment: Well, @bheklilr gave basically the way I did it. (Though I swapped `drop 1` for `tail`. If there's no better way, I'll go with that.

Comment: @RamithJayatilleka I personally just stick with `drop 1` over `tail` since `tail` is a partial function and I try not to use it.  In this case, we're guaranteed that it'll succeed so it's fine to use, I've just gotten in the habit of ignoring the fact `tail` even exists.

Comment: Your original zipWith implementation is better than any of the suggested variants in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you and bheklilr mention, `cycle` provides a nice way to accomplish this. You can take advantage of laziness a bit though:

```
mapEvery :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapEvery n f = zipWith ($) (drop 1 . cycle . take n $ f : repeat id)
```

The use of `zipWith` and `cycle` seems more idiomatic (complex behavior composed from simpler behaviors) than a hand-written recursive function that combines both tasks.

*Note*: `tail` here makes this function undefined for `n = 0` so `drop 1` is preferable.

There isn't a library function for this that I'm aware of.

Comment: Doing something to every 0th element of a list is probably nonsense, so it's better for the function to fail in that case. If it does happen to make sense in a particular context, you should figure out what the appropriate behavior is for n=0, not make the function total in some arbitrary way in the name of "safety". Luckily cycle [] is an error already, so changing tail to drop 1 has no effect.

Comment: Nice work switching the `replicate` to `take`. I think that's cleaner, I'll use this. Thanks.